# Getting error in protractor POM implementation

Tags: javascript, node.js, angularjs, selenium-webdriver, protractor

I have created 3 different files 1)config.js 2)Homepage.js 3)TestScript.js, I am getting an error while executing config.js

Please help me rectify it.

Test Environment versions are the following:-
Protractor Version 5.4.3
Node 12.14.1
npm 6.13.4

Error:-

> PS E:\Protractor\ProtractorWithPOM\conf> protractor config.js
>   [10:03:18] I/launcher - Running 1 instances of WebDriver [10:03:18]
>   I/hosted - Using the selenium server at http://localhost:4444/wd/hub
>   [10:03:25] E/launcher - missing field `url` at line 2 column 1 Build
>   info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time:
>   '2018-11-14T08:25:53' System info: host: 'DESKTOP-OTBQBN0', ip:
>   '192.168.229.2', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version:
>   '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_231' Driver info: driver.version: unknown
>   [10:03:25] E/launcher - WebDriverError: missing field `url` at line 2
>   column 1 Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358',
>   time: '2018-11-14T08:25:53' System info: host: 'DESKTOP-OTBQBN0', ip:
>   '192.168.229.2', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version:
>   '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_231' Driver info: driver.version: unknown
>       at Object.checkLegacyResponse (C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\error.js:546:15)
>       at parseHttpResponse (C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\http.js:509:13)
>       at C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\http.js:441:30
>       at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:94:5) From: Task:
>   WebDriver.navigate().to(undefined)
>       at thenableWebDriverProxy.schedule (C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\webdriver.js:807:17)
>       at Navigation.to (C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\webdriver.js:1133:25)
>       at thenableWebDriverProxy.get (C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\webdriver.js:988:28)
>       at new  (E:\Protractor\ProtractorWithPOM\pages\Homepage.js:8:24)
>       at new Homepage (E:\Protractor\ProtractorWithPOM\pages\Homepage.js:7:17)
>       at Object. (E:\Protractor\ProtractorWithPOM\pages\Homepage.js:26:15)
>       at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:955:30)
>       at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:991:10)
>       at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:811:32)
>       at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:723:14) [10:03:25] E/launcher - Process exited with error code 199

Config.js

```
var HtmlReporter = require('protractor-beautiful-reporter');

exports.config = {

  seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub',
  capabilities: { 
   browserName: 'firefox', 
   browserVersion: '72.0.2'
   },
  specs: ['E:\\Protractor\\ProtractorWithPOM\\tests\\TestScript.js'],

 onPrepare: function() {

      jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(new HtmlReporter({
         baseDirectory: 'Reports/screenshots'
      }).getJasmine2Reporter());
   }

};
```

Homepage.js

```
let Homepage= function(){

    var accept_Cookies=element(by.id('cookieConfirmationButton'));
    var cityname=element(by.id("googlePlace"));
    var area=element(by.id('myInput'));

    this.getURL=new function(url){
        browser.driver.get(url);

    };

    this.acceptCookie=new function(){
        accept_Cookies.click();
    };

    this.entercityName=new function(cityname){
        cityname.sendKeys(cityname);

    };
    this.enterareaname=new function(areaname){
        area.sendKeys(areaname);

    }

};
module.export=new Homepage();
```

Testscript.js

```
let Homepage= require('../pages/Homepage');

describe("This is my pratractor test", function(){


    it("TC0:This is Generali Global Health Provider Project", function(){

        browser.driver.manage().window().maximize();

        Homepage.getURL('https://pffrontendprod.azureedge.net/search');

        expect(browser.driver.getTitle()).toEqual('Generali Global Health Provider Search');

    });

    it("TC1: Verify Search", function(){

        Homepage.acceptCookie();
        Homepage.entercityName("Navi Mumbai, Maharashtra, India");
        Homepage.enterareaname("Fortis Hiranandani Hospital");

    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Refer this

[image]

TestScript.js

```
let hmpage = require('../pages/Homepage').Homepage;

describe("This is my pratractor test", () => {


    it("TC0:This is Generali Global Health Provider Project", () => {
        hmpage.getURL('https://pffrontendprod.azureedge.net/search');
        expect(browser.driver.getTitle()).toEqual('Generali Global Health Provider Search');
    });

    it("TC1: Verify Search", () => {
        hmpage.acceptCookie();
        hmpage.entercityName("Navi Mumbai, Maharashtra, India");
        hmpage.enterareaname("Fortis Hiranandani Hospital");
    });
});
```

Homepage.js

```
let locators = {
    accept_Cookies: browser.driver.element(by.id('cookieConfirmationButton')),
    cityname: browser.driver.element(by.id("googlePlace")),
    area: browser.driver.element(by.id('myInput'))
};

let methods = {
    getURL: (url) => {
        browser.driver.get(url);
    },
    acceptCookie: () => {
        locators.accept_Cookies.click();
    },
    entercityName: (cityname) => {
        locators.cityname.sendKeys(cityname);
    },
    enterareaname: (areaname) => {
        locators.area.sendKeys(areaname);
    }
}

exports.Homepage = { locators, methods };
```

Comment: Hi Bharath. Thanks for  quick response. I am getting the following error "Failed: Homepage.acceptCookie is not a function". Could you help me to rectify it

Comment: Kindly refer question description. I already posted code there.

Comment: Can you upload your spec and page file alone in a git repo and share the URL. I will update the changes

Comment: Please refer git https://github.com/vpkhachane/protractordemo.git